# Object Permissions on EmailMessage Object

Tags: permissions, sharing, emailmessage

No object level permissions appear to exist for the `EmailMessage` object is this true?

Comment: I just stumbled upon this. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @RichardKiefer no solution simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @jordan.baucke did you figure this out ? I can't grant permission to this object to a specific group of people.

Comment: , @RichardKiefer did you figure this out ?